# Why is the the following statement not equivalent to compactness?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Well it comes down to word-play again. I'm confused to the core of my bones as to why the following isn't equivalent to saying that a space is compact

> Every open cover is finite.

A compact set must have **every** open cover in which there is a finite subcover.

Well, the statement tells me that every single possible open cover is finite. So...why doesn't this qualify?

Subcover needn't be a proper subset/cover so if I have every open cover being finite...the open cover itself can act as a subcover(which is of course finite) so voila, we're done..no?

Elaborate explanation much appreciated on this

Comment: You are quite right that, if every open cover is finite, then every oven cover has a finite subcover. You haven't explained why you think that, if every open cover has a finite subcover, then every open cover is finite.

Comment: Well, isn't it because I can let the open cover itself be a subcover of itself? It needn't be a proper subcover like I said so I must be allowed to do this. That's why every open cover has a finite subcover *in this case*.

Comment: When you say two things are equivalent, it means that "A if and only if B". In this case, you're saying a set is compact if and only if every open cover is finite. The example below presents the case of a finite subcover, but with an infinite cover. You can't just deny the existence of infinite covers because you'd rather deal with the finite covers. They're still there, so a compact set necessarily doesn't have only finite subcovers.

Comment: As for the example...indeed, it presents an *infinite* open cover. But, the statement says if a particular space has every possible open cover be *finite* (therefore, we need not worry nor talk about finding a *infinite* open cover) it is compact. So we know that we have *finite* open covers for every possible open covers. None infinite. Considering the case of an *infinite* open cover's existence already violates the statement's *finite* open cover bit so I don't see how this would answer my confusion...

Comment: Then I guess you['d say there is no difference between the statements "every integer greater than one has a prime divisor" and "every integer greater than one is a prime number", right? Because, an integer is a divisor of itself, so the prime divisor could be the number itself?

Comment: I think that analogy is slightly different from the confusion I've been having...but I've understood the problem below, so it's all good now for this one. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compact space is one in which every open cover has *a* finite subcover. Not every subcover has to be finite. So, for example, the cover $C = \{(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\,|\, 0 < \varepsilon\}$ is an open cover of $[-1,1]$, and has as a finite subcover the singleton $\{(-2,2)\}$. The cover is still infinite, however.

Comment: I still don't get it; *a* subcover, so if I can find at least one finite subcover of each open cover, it's compact yes? The statement says *every* open cover is finite. Thus, if I let open cover=open subcover for each, I've found one finite subcover for each case. Therefore, it must be compact. I think in your example the open cover is *infinite* but the statement in question assumes that *every open cover IS FINITE* so it doesn't really relate to my question?

Comment: The point of compactness is that every open cover, whether infinite or not, has a finite subcover. That means that for every open cover you can throw away all but finitely many sets and still have a cover. So for example, $[0,1]$ is compact, and one open cover of this is the collection I mentioned. Since $[0,1]$ is compact, there must be a finite subcover of this; I have mentioned one possible finite subcover.

Comment: I'm sweating right now, I still don't understand(sorry)... I mean, aren't we considering a space which every open cover is *finite*? I think the statement's saying "if the space you're looking at happens to have every open cover to be finite, it's compact". In your words, in a sense, I need not throw away anything from each open cover. So shouldn't it be compact? I guess I'm missing a point you're trying to make but I just can't see the relation to my question.....

Comment: No, compactness does not mean that every open cover is finite. The condition of compactness is this: "Every open cover has a finite *subcover*". Nowhere does compactness say every open cover is finite. Compactness does not say that.

Comment: Yes yes, so if every open cover is finite for a space, the subcover is the open cover itself(which is given to be finite). Thus compact. Where's the flaw?

Comment: If every open cover is finite, then yes, the space is compact. But compactness does not imply that every open cover is finite. This is not an if and only if statement.

Comment: Oh, wait so are you saying that "every open cover is finite $\Rightarrow$ compact" is true. BUT "compact $\Rightarrow$ every open cover is finite" is NOT true and that's the issue?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying.

Comment: Brilliant, I finally got what you're saying, thanks for the help I feel better now.

Comment: @JohnTrail Isn't that just what I said half an hour ago when I commented: "You are quite right that, if every open cover is finite, then every oven cover has a finite subcover. You haven't explained why you think that, if every open cover has a finite subcover, then every open cover is finite." WHAT DID I DO WRONG? Was my mistake using the words "if . . . then" instead of the symbol "$\implies$"?

Comment: @bof I think it was more of the "if and only if" thing that I needed. When you said "you haven't explained why..." bit, I didn't quite understand what you meant because, you affirmed that "you are quite right that...has a finite subcover" but seemed to be asking for "*why*" I can justify that. I think I would've gotten it if you pointed out that the "reverse" argument i.e. "compact then every open cover is finite" is not correct.

Comment: @bof Lol, I guess your only mistake was not reasoning back and forth for 20 minutes until it could finally "click" in OP's head. (Nothing personal, OP :)

Comment: @JohnTrail So instead of saying "you're quite right that $A\implies B$ but you haven't explained why $B\implies A$ I should have said "you're quite right that $A\implies B$ but you're wrong about $B\implies A$"? Got it. I'll try and remember to be more direct next time.

Comment: Yes, I guess, I mean thanks to both of you (or everyone actually) for trying to help. Topology is just not my cup of tea and unlike some people who seem to instantly get the hang of it, I think my DNA doesn't have the circuit to run with abstract and vague thoughts...topology seems like half logic+half intuition/senses. As much as I want to do something that suits me, I've an exam in a bit so I'll probably be coming back often for more questions. Direct answers would most likely help indeed :)

Comment: Don't worry about it too much. I certainly felt like I was drowning in abstraction when I first encountered topology. It just takes time to get used to the formal notions that topology is built out of. Furthermore, it's oftentimes better to peel away at the abstraction a layer at a time, dealing with progressively more general spaces as you acclimate to the more "intuitive" ones. So, for example, manifold topology is much nicer than general metric space topology, which in turn is much easier to deal with than general abstract topological spaces...

Comment: With practice, eventually you start to see the utility of each of the axioms and how one works with them in practice. Furthermore, you rarely ever need the full generalization of abstract topological spaces, since in practice most of the spaces you work with will satisfy some additional axioms that will make your life much easier, like the Hausdorff condition. In general topological spaces, you will get all sorts of bizarre behavior that you won't see in spaces that satisfy, e.g. Hausdorff condition or second-countability.